# Select box option value on right-click: without using option:selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

My question is different than just "how do I get the selected option from a select box".

In select box, no option element is 'selected' prior to right-clicking on it.
On right-clicking an option, I want to get the value of that option element.

Therefore, `option:selected` won't work.

```
<select name='mySel' id='mySel' multiple>
  <option value='val1'>myOption1</option>
  <option value='val2'>myOption2</option>
</select>
```

I have bound `rightclick` event to the context menu:

```
// bind right click event to context menu
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.rightClick = function(method) {
  $(this).bind('contextmenu rightclick', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    method();
    return false;
    })

  };
    })( jQuery );
```

The event handler code below will only work if an option is selected prior to right clicking:

```
$('#mySel').rightClick(function(e){
  alert($('#mySel option:selected').text());
    });
```

Without using `option:selected`, how do I get the value of right-clicked option?

Comment: The first question that comes to mind: WHY?

Comment: 1) In order to remove that option from the list, and 2) get val of that option and send to server for deletion (after submit)

Comment: also check out the source for the 'Right-Click' plugin: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin/, it does similar stuff...

Comment: As far as possible, I try to avoid plugins. Although individual plugin is lightweight, including a loads of plugins would add an overhead for page loading. Any comment on this appreciated. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target property of the event parameter will refer to the element which triggered the event, in your case the option element that was right-clicked:

```
$('#txBase').rightClick(function(e){
  alert(e.target.value); // val1 or val2
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/nKQNC/)**

A few notes about your code:

- no need to `return false` and to `e.preventDefault`, both statement have the same result so just use one or the other
- you might wanna check if `method` is not undefined and is a function before calling it, otherwise it will break
- when you call `method`, pass the parameter `e` to it otherwise you won't be able to use inside your callback

Here's the modified code:

```
$(this).bind('contextmenu rightclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (method && $.isFunction(method)) {
        method(e); // pass the event parameter to your callback
    }

})
```

Comment: @Didler Ghys, thank you very much. Your code worked. I have accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name='mySel' id='mySel' multiple>
<option value='val1' oncontextmenu="getValue(this);return false">myOption1</option>
<option value='val2' oncontextmenu="getValue(this);return false">myOption2</option>
</select>
<div id="status"></div>
<script>
function getValue(t){
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=t.value;    
}  
</script>
```

What about this?